# Save different csv files as one excel workbook with multiple sheets

Tags: r

I am trying to use the xlsx package to put different csv files into one excel workbook with multiple sheets. I found a routine that should work but it is not working for me.

So I have different csv files:

```
S:/productivity/R/Results/2008.csv 
S:/productivity/R/Results/2009.csv
S:/productivity/R/Results/2010.csv
S:/productivity/R/Results/2011.csv
S:/productivity/R/Results/2012.csv
```

My R codes look like:

```
# loading the library
library(xlsx)
rm(list = ls())

# getting the path of all csv files
myfiles = system("S:/productivity/R/Results",intern = TRUE)

wb <- createWorkbook()


# going through each csv file
for (item in myfiles) {

    # create a sheet in the workbook
    sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName=strsplit(item,"/")[[1]][5])

    # add the data to the new sheet
    addDataFrame(read.csv(item), sheet)
}

# saving the workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, "2008_2012.xlsx")
```

I receive the following error:

> myfiles = system('"S:/productivity/R/Results"',intern = TRUE)
>   Error in system("\"S:/productivity/R/Results\"", intern = TRUE) :
>   '"S:/productivity/R/Results"' not found

Comment: I like `xlsx`, but I found that when multiple sheets are involved, `XLConnect` is a lot easier to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I use `XLConnect` for these tasks.

The steps for writing to multiple sheets are:

- create a new workbook
- create the sheet
- output the data to the sheet
- save the sheet

--

#### SAMPLE CODE:

```
library(data.table)  ## for fast fread() function
library(XLConnect)

folder <- "folder/where/CSV_files_are_located"

f.out <- "path/to/file.xlsx"

## load in file
wb <- loadWorkbook(f.out, create=TRUE)

## get all files
pattern.ext <- "\\.csv$"
files <- dir(folder, full=TRUE, pattern=pattern.ext)

## Grab the base file names, you can use them as the sheet names
files.nms <- basename(files)
files.nms <- gsub(pattern.ext, "", files.nms)

## set the names to make them easier to grab
names(files) <- files.nms

for (nm in files.nms) {
  ## ingest the CSV file
  temp_DT <- fread(files[[nm]])

  ## Create the sheet where the file will be outputed to 
  createSheet(wb, name=nm)

  ## output the csv contents
  writeWorksheet(object=wb, data=temp_DT, sheet=nm, header=TRUE, rownames=NULL)
}

saveWorkbook(wb)
```

#### if you would like to see your file

```
system(sprintf("open %s", dirname(f.out)))  ## For the containing folder
system(sprintf("open %s", f.out))  ## for opening the file with default app, ie excel
```

Comment: K. Thanks. Let me try it and I will get back to you.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, so your routine works fine until it hits the fread function. I got an error:
> temp_DT <- fread(files[[nm]])
Error in files[[nm]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: To help resolve the error, I am providing the following values > files.nms
[1] "DEA_np_2008" "DEA_np_2009" "DEA_np_2010" "DEA_np_2011" "DEA_np_2012" "DEA_np_2013"
> nm
[1] "DEA_np_2008"

Comment: My "files" looks like this: > files
[1] "R/Results_v2/DEA_np_2008.csv" "R/Results_v2/DEA_np_2009.csv"
[3] "R/Results_v2/DEA_np_2010.csv" "R/Results_v2/DEA_np_2011.csv"
[5] "R/Results_v2/DEA_np_2012.csv" "R/Results_v2/DEA_np_2013.csv"

Comment: The problem was that nm was a string var of the file name prefix. I edited the code as follows to make it work. i <-0
for (nm in files) {
  ## ingest the CSV file
  temp_DT <- fread(nm)
  
  ## Create the sheet where the file will be outputed to 
  i <-i+1
  fn <-files.nms[i]
  createSheet(wb, name=fn)
  
  ## output the csv contents
  writeWorksheet(object=wb, data=temp_DT, sheet=i, header=TRUE, rownames=NULL)
}

Comment: hi, if you used the line `names(files) <- files.nms` then you shouldnt hit that error.   but either way, i am glad it is working for you

Comment: Hi there, you are right. I forgot to run that line! Your entire routine is now running just fine. Thanks. So does the names function essentially create a hash table?

Comment: nope, the `names()` function assigns an attribute to the given object.  see `?names`     -- by the way, backticks (`\``) allow you to quote code in the comments